# Rails - increment variable in fields_for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm hoping this is a simple question - I have the following helper code:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def add_feature_fields(feature_types, object_form_builder, actions_visible)
    feature_types.length.times {object_form_builder.object.features.build}
    i = 0
    fields = object_form_builder.fields_for :features do |features_builder|
      render :partial => "features/fixed_feature", :locals => {:feature => features_builder, :fixed_feature_type => feature_types[i], :form_actions_visible => actions_visible}
      i = i + 1
    end
  end
end
```

The code is working as expected, except for the line `i = i + 1`. For some reason, this seems to be breaking the loop, and nothing is rendered. Evidently, I am doing this wrong somehow - perhaps fields_for is not a normal loop?

How can I increment i by 1 each time the loop runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def add_feature_fields(feature_types, object_form_builder, actions_visible)
    feature_types.length.times {object_form_builder.object.features.build}
    i = -1
    object_form_builder.fields_for :features do |features_builder|
      i = i + 1
      render :partial => "features/fixed_feature", :locals => {:feature => features_builder, :fixed_feature_type => feature_types[i], :form_actions_visible => actions_visible}
    end
  end
end
```

I believe what was happening was that when I did `i = i + 1` after I called render, the return value was the iterator and not render (since the method returns the last value).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the below code, but something around this should work and fix the issue. Give a try

```
object_form_builder.each.with_index do |builder,index|
  object_form_builder.fields_for :features, builder do |feature_builder|
      render :partial => "features/fixed_feature", :locals => {:feature => features_builder, :fixed_feature_type => feature_types[i], :form_actions_visible => actions_visible}
  end
end
```